# COUNT the active user and in active user in database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a problem with the number of active and inactive users in the database by C# and ASP.net. We have two value in statues "active" and "inactive". I want label "none" to show the count of active users and label "inone" label to show the inactive.

```
  private void countactivelUser()
    {
        //string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS [status]   from users ";
        string queryString = "select  COUNT(*) AS [status]   from users ";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                //var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*)  From users Order By Id desc", con);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //cmd.Parameters["@status"].Value = "active";             

                int a = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                none.Text = a.ToString();// this show activeuser 
                inone.Text = a.ToString(); // this show inactive user 

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'll guess the column is called status.
You're counting all of the statuses. So your query needs to count based on status type:

```
SELECT status,COUNT(status) FROM users GROUP BY status
```

You should then get multiple rows with counts based on whatever statuses you have.

For the reset you probably want to use [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.8) (example there)